# No module named 'pvlib.temperature'

Tags: pvlib

I am going through the pvlib documentation right now ("A simple ModelChain example") and when I try to import 
`from pvlib.temperature import TEMPERATURE_MODEL_PARAMETERS` I receive the message that the module `pvlib.temperature` does not exist. Is the documentation not up to date or am I missing something?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chrisomer can you share the link to the documentation you are reading?  I don't see the `from pvlib.temperature…` statement in [current docs](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

You might be looking at docs for the current master branch on pvlib rather than for latest release v0.6.3. The `pvlib.temperature` module has been added since v0.6.3 and will be in the next release v0.7.

Comment: The documentation that I am using is the one linked on github [docs](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). You are right I guess because the one I am using is the 'latest' while the one you linked is the 'stable' documentation. Thanks